# Tabulator - Ajax Load, Search Input URL Parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax, tabulator

Using Tabulator 5.4

I am using Bootstrap 4 input box and search botton, sample code below is for dropdown selector, Need help in modifying evend from select box to Input box (with out form).

Bootstrap Search box code:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" id="productSearch">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Tabulator Ajax Load URL Parameters code, this need to be changed to trigger ajaxLoad with URL Parameter ex. URL ?searchval=Pen

Below is example code is based on bootstrap selectpicker, this need to be modified.

```
$(function () {
    $('select').selectpicker();
});

let table = new Tabulator("#My-Table", {  
            layout:"fitColumns",
            pagination:true,  
            pagination: "remote", 
            paginationSize: 30, 
            ajaxURL: "/backend/getdata.php",             
            ajaxParams: {
                "srcParam": $('.selectpicker').val()
            },
});

// Below Selector / Event handler to be changed to get input value from Search field input box on button click/press.

$('#mySelect').on('changed.bs.select', function (e, clickedIndex, isSelected, previousValue) {
  console.log($('.selectpicker').val())
  table.setData()
});
```

when search button is clicked,  value typed in search box is printed in console.
Not able to figure out on how to make it work with table.serData() to copy searchboc value to URL Parameter.

```
document.getElementById("searchbutton").addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log(document.getElementById("productSearch").value
});
```